# Unity OnTriggerEnter Activate Automatically when i Start the Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ? I have code  in my `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` method that should ONLY get called when I cross the box's collider, but when I start a game the code gets called at once.

Unity's `OnTriggerEnter` seems to activate automatically when I start the game. How can I prevent that ? I made sure that the player has a collider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource Scream;
    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject JumpCam;
    public GameObject FlashImg;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Scream.Play();
        JumpCam.SetActive(true);
        ThePlayer.SetActive(false);
        FlashImg.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine (EndJump ());
    }

    IEnumerator EndJump()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        ThePlayer.SetActive(true);
        JumpCam.SetActive(false);
        FlashImg.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you start the Game you are already in the Box Collider. Resulting in the Activation of the `OnTriggerEnter()` Function.

To guarantee that it only triggers when the player crosses the Box Collider Border Use [OnTriggerExit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html)